# python py2app help

Tags: python, py2app

I tried using py2app, but I can't figure out where to put the filename of the file I want to make the standalone for. What command do I need to run? I'm extremely confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [docs](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#create-a-setup-py-file) - you pass name of your file to py2applet script.

```
$ py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py
Wrote setup.py
$ python setup.py py2app -A
```

And IMHO - [pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) - is the best tool for python binaries building.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out about a minute ago. Still, very useful to know I'm doing it right! :)

Comment: might be for windows systems, but for mac ,after many tries still can't get it to produce an app that runs

Answer (score 4):

In your `setup.py`, you want to do something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2app

setup(name="App name",
      version="App version",
      options=opts, # see the py2app docs, could be a lot of things
      app=[main.py], # This is the standalone script
     )
```